# Остановить работу программы, если введенное поле не получается конвертировать в число C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

Пишу программу, которая проводит анализ числа (кол-во разрядов, четность и тд.) используя WindowsForms. Работает программа верно, но при вводе букв, программа вылетает, нужно сделать так, что бы если строку не получается конвертировать в число, программа выводила MessageBox и давала возможность заново ввести число. Как это реализовать?

```
int number;
number = Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text);
```

и далее остальной код. Вот на этом этапе нужно проверить корректность данных.

Comment: Используйте [try/catch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/try-catch) или [TryParse](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Для ввода чисел используйте `NumericUpDown` вместо `TextBox`. Также посмотрите `MaskedTextBox`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: пример работы]

Используйте классы модели приложения и привязки.
Нам нужно в окне получить число и вывести в лейбл некий текст. Создадим такой класс

```
class MainViewData
{
    public int Number { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
```

И такой код в форме

```
public partial class MainView : Form
{
    //источник данных для привязки
    private MainViewData _inputData = new MainViewData
    {
        Description = "Если введено неверное значение " +
        "\nв TextBox, то невозможно перейти к кнопке " +
        "\nили даже закрыть окно."
    };

    public MainView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //установка привязок
        SetBindings();

        this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
        this.Text = "Пример";

        buttonOK.Click += ButtonOK_Click;
    }

    private void SetBindings()
    {
        //создаем объект привязки
        Binding tbNumber = new Binding("Text", _inputData, nameof(MainViewData.Number), true);
        //назначаем привязку для TextBox
        textBoxNumber.DataBindings.Add(tbNumber);

        //назначаем привязку для Lable
        labelDescription.DataBindings.Add("Text", _inputData, nameof(MainViewData.Description));
    }

    private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Введено число: {_inputData.Number}");
    }
}
```

Если же нам из кода необходимо, допустим в лейбл вывести некий результат, тогда в классе модели сделаем небольшое дополнение

```
class MainViewData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    public int Number { get; set; }

    private string _description;
    public string Description
    {
        get => _description;
        set
        {
            _description = value;
            //вызываем событие, чтоб
            //лейбл обновил значение
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Description)));
        }
    }

    //вычислем и выводим результат
    public void GetResult()
    {
        var result = Number * 2;
        Description = $"Получилось {result}";
    }
}
```

И слегка дополним обработчик клика на кнопке

```
private void ButtonOK_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show($"Введено число: {_inputData.Number}");

    //вычислем результат в классе модели
    //и выводим результат
    _inputData.GetResult();
}
```

После этих изменений

[image: пример 2]